# Clustering based on maximum inertia

Tags: clustering

Is there a way to perform clustering based on inertia threshold where each cluster inertia can’t exceed an inertia a specific inertia

I have tried hierarchical clustering with complete linkage with distance threshold, yet i can’t control the total distances of a cluster.

More info:

Im using precomputed distance matrix
The main goal here is to divide destinations between drivers using roads network (distance matrix of destinations)

Answer (score 0):

K-means objective function is to minimize total variance among all clusters. Hierarchial clustering objective function is to keep distance between two clusters within a threshold.
Your objective function is to keep variance within clusters within a threshold. This does not fit into K-means or Hierarchial.

You need to use a mix of Kmeans and Hierarchial.

What you can do is run a loop from 2 till n_points. Set number of clusters as variable. Run K-means and estimate variance in all clusters. Stop loop when variance in any cluster goes above threshold.

Warn: This is computationally expensive exercise. You can try running not from 2 but a higher number

Comment: Actually, i did something similar by tracing the hierarchy linkage output  (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) from top to bottom and assign all clusters which meet defined threshold.